# Redis runs out of memory cause slow query but can not find in slow log

Tags: redis, nosql

I have query take seconds to get a key from redis sometimes.
Redis info shows used_memory is 2 times lager than used_memory_rss and OS starts to use swap.
After cleaning the useless data, used_memory is lower than used_memory_rss and everything goes fine.

what confuse me is: if any query cost like 10 second and block other query to redis would lead serious problem to other part of the app, but it seems fine to the app. 
And I can not find any of this long time query in slow log, so I check redis  SLOWLOG command and it says

*The execution time does not include I/O operations like talking with the client, sending the reply and so forth, but just the time needed to actually execute the command (this is the only stage of command execution where the thread is blocked and can not serve other requests in the meantime)*

so if this means the execution of the query is normal and not blocking any other queries? What happen to the query when memory is not enough and lead this long time query? Which part of these query takes so long since "actually execute the command" time cost not long enough to get into slowlog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When memory is not enough Redis will definitely  slow down as it will start swapping .You can use  INFO to report the amount of memory Redis is using ,even you can set a max limit to memory usage, using the maxmemory option in the config file to put a limit to the memory Redis can use. If this limit is reached Redis will start to reply with an error to write commands (but will continue to accept read-only commands),

Comment: Thanks. Everything goes fine after optimizing memory. But I still do not know which part of these query takes so long since these query "actually execute the command" is not long enough to get into slow log.

Comment: Have you tried enhanced Redis Slow Log feature?

https://redislabs.com/blog/enhancing-redis-slow-log#.V154cvl97IU

Comment: thanks for this link and I think this feather is great for complex commands. But I only use "get" command and also these slow queries happens during  get a string from redis.

Comment: I do not know if i get this right: if a query takes 10 seconds then this query must appears in slowlog and if this query do not in slowlog, then the actually execute is normal. Then what part of a query would cost so much time?

Comment: one case would be if you have lots of data being returned, so, redis would return instantly, but the data travelling over the network can slow your queries down, so if that is the case, you can go on the server and try to execute the "get" query to check.

Comment: Thanks, this also the first thing come to my mind. I check these command in redis client right after I got warning message. But first these query are not always slow, about 5 times amount 100 queries, so it is hard to find some clue in redis-cli. Second after  optimizing memory this problem is solved so I don't think this is cause by network IO.